Can we conclude provibility from semantically equavalency?
Let $\varphi$ be formula that $\varphi \equiv \perp$, i. e. for all valuaition $V$ we have $V(\varphi) = \varphi(\perp) = 0$. Can we conclude that $\vdash \varphi \leftrightarrow \perp$?
Does it important in which logical system we are in?
Edit: In the case we have completeness, then it would be obvious we do have $\vdash \varphi \leftrightarrow \perp$. What if we are not aware about completeness?

Yes... provided that the proof system is complete, i.e. it proves all valid formulas.

@MauroALLEGRANZA But what if we only have soundness and are not aware whether completeness holds or not?

I don't follow how we have a guarantee of '↔' as a valid connective.  So, I don't understand how we could conclude that '⊢φ↔⊥'.

@DougSpoonwood Assume $\rightarrow$ is valid and $x\leftrightarrow y$ is defined as $x\rightarrow y ,&, y\rightarrow x$.
Actually, my guess is this statement is equivalent to completeness.

" Assume → is valid and x↔y is defined as x→y&y→x."
Then '↔' likely is not a symbol in the formal system, since it gets defined in terms of the primitives of the system.  So, no we could not conclude ⊢φ↔⊥.

Yes, it is important to know what proof system you are in. Provability is always relative to a formal proof system. Indeed, instead of using $\vdash \phi$, we really should be using $\vdash_S \phi$, which says: "$\phi$ can be derived in proof system $S$"
Why is this important?  Well, who knows what kinds of rules $S$ does or does not have. To give two extremes:

Consider the 'null' system $N$ that contains no inference rules whatsoever.

Obviously, nothing can be derived in proof system $N$, and so $\vdash_N \phi$ will always be false, even if $\vDash \phi$ is true.

Consider the 'Hokus Ponens' system $HP$ that contains a single inference rule called 'Hokus Ponens':

\begin{array}{}
\hline
\phi\\
\end{array}
Obviously, in this system we can derive anything we want, and so we have $\vdash_{HP} \phi$ for any $\phi$, including statements $\phi$ for which it is not true that $\vDash \phi$
Making this all-important distinction between semantical validity ($\vDash$) and syntactical provability ($\vdash_S$) allows us to ask two important questions relative to any proof system $S$:

Is our proof system $S$ sound?  That is:  is it true that for any $\phi$:  If $\vdash_S \phi$ then $\vDash \phi$?

Note that of the above two systems, $N$ is sound, but $HP$ is not.

Is our proof system $S$ comeplte?  That is:  is it true that for any $\phi$:  If $\vDash \phi$ then $\vdash_S \phi$?

Note that of the above two systems, $HP$ is complete, but $N$ is not.
OK, so $N$ is sounds but not complete, while $HP$ is complte but not sound. But obviously we want proof systems that are both sound and complete, and for both propositional logic and quantificational logic there are such proof systems. In fact, unless some text committed a horrible faux pas, you can safely assume that any proof system for first-order logic that you are presented with will be both sound and complete. Indeed, this is so standard that people will drop the suffix, and simply use $\vdash$.

"In fact, ... , you can safely assume that any proof system for first-order logic that you are presented with will be both sound and complete."
If one pays close attention to the definition of a formal proof, with a higher degree of rigor, I suspect that the same person would infer a different conclusion.  Note a formal proof consists of a finite sequence of marks in a text.  But, often there exists an infinity of semantically valid statements.  The set of existing formal proofs is finite and always will be finite.  So, the set of theorems is finite.  Consequently, we have incompleteness.

The necessary mismatch between provable theorems and semantically valid statements also doesn't happen because of the nature of first-order logic.  I mean, the same thing happens for a propositional logic with an infinity of semantically valid statements as soon as we get rigorous about the definition of formal proofs.
Also, I think it fair to point out that semantically valid statements get stated far more than formal proofs get produced.  And the highest standard seems that no statement is a formal theorem unless formally proven.

"Obviously, nothing can be derived in proof system N, and so ⊢Nϕ will always be false, even if ⊨ϕ is true."
But, isn't '⊢(φ↔⊥)' false then, given (φ↔⊥) as a well-formed formula?

@DougSpoonwood If by 'existing' you mean 'existing in our universe', then sure, there are and will be only finitely formal proofs. But in the world of mathematics, there are infinitely many formal proofs, just as in mathematics there are infinitely many numbers, etc. And that's what we mean by $\vdash \phi$: mathematically there exists a formal derivation of $\phi$ .. we don't mean to say that such a derivation exists in our world.

And yes, $\vdash_N \varphi \leftrightarrow \bot$ is false: there is no derivation in $N$ of the statement $\varphi \leftrightarrow \bot$
